# How can I get list of all data set codes of Quandl API?

Tags: quandl

I want list of all dataset codes for each company,Ex. for Facebook dataset code is FB,for MICROSOFT it is MSFT.How can I get such list of all available codes for data sets ??

Comment: Those are ticker symbols. Have you read the documentation from Quandl? https://docs.quandl.com/docs/in-depth-usage-1

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of all the available datasets in a database provided you have the database name.

```
GET https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets?database_code=<database-name>&api_key=<api-key>
```

Replace the value `<database-name>` and `<api-key>` in the above URL. This will return a list of dataset object. Each object will have a `dataset_code` field having the required value.

Make sure you register on the [quandl website](https://www.quandl.com/) for getting the access key. You do not have to pay or give credit card details for registration.

For JSON response you can use the below. Also you can mention the current page and page size as below -

```
https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets.json?database_code=${databaseCode}&api_key=${apiKey}&current_page=${currentPage}&per_page=${perPage}
```

Comment: Anything to do with quandl is dead now. So this information is unfortunately buried under rubble.